# Best way to connect to a really small berg connector

Tags: pcb, connector

I am using the cc2520emk to interface with an external mcu. I know the pinout of each but I do not know how to make a good connection with my MCU. THe mcu is not the issue. I can stick in Bergs and use a breadboard to prototype. The problem is the cc2520 which has really small berg connectors. I really dont know how to connect them or what these bergs are called. I am attaching a snapshot of how they look so you guys can tell me what berg to buy. In the parts list it says 
P1          SMD pinrow socket, .050 spacinSMD_SOCKET_2X10 . So does that mean a berg connector with 0.05 inch spacing will fit correctly?

[image]

Comment: Where are your calipers?

Comment: Dont have them. I have to get it

Comment: What do you want to connect this cc2520 card to: breadboard, or a PCB ?

Comment: First breadboard , breadboard to MCU

Comment: Your use of the term "berg" leads me to suspect you might be based in India, or some nearby country, where that term is routinely misused.

Comment: Yep. I am in India

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CC2520 board is intended to work as a daughter for TI LaunchPads ([like this one](http://www.ti.com/tool/msp-exp430fr5739)).  The combination looks something like this.

[image]

The LaunchPad has corresponding male connectors.  You can probably track down the exact part numbers for these connectors.

As Anindo had mentioned above, the pitch (distance between pins) is 1.27 mm [0.05 inch].  The holes on the breadboard have 2.54 mm [0.10 inch] pitch.  They don't match.

You could get an adepter: [BOOST-CCEMADAPTER](http://www.ti.com/tool/boost-ccemadapter) .

You can un-solder the female connector from the CC2520 board, solder wires instead plug them into the breadboard.  I've done that, and it was handy.

[image]

The orange daughter card in these pictures is Anaren A2500R24C-EM1

Comment: The boost adapter is really nice

Answer (score 2):

Those are 50 mil spacing double-row pin headers (10x2, 0.05 inch / 1.27 mm pitch).

Suitable pin strips should be found by searching on your preferred electronic components site.

I found these on [eBay](http://www.ebay.com/itm/10-PCS-100-Pin-1-27MM-Gold-Plated-Double-Row-Straight-Male-Pin-Header-/281111565553?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item41738e14f1) "10 PCS 100 Pin 1.27MM Gold Plated Double Row Straight Male Pin Header" for $4.99 including shipping:

[image]

The term "[Berg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berg_strip)" is not applicable, as Berg connectors are a specific brand of pin headers and connectors made by a specific company and have a 2.54 mm (0.1 inch) pitch.

Comment: So can I add *"Berg connector"* to *"Molex connector"*, *"JST connector"* and *"IEC plug"* in my list of vague and misleading connector names? :-)

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick Don't forget "*vampire connector*", which seems a popular term for IDC. Ooooh, the visual imagery of that one!